# Custom Function Not Found In debug.log File

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, function, file-upload

I am creating one plugin and it's for contact forms and they have file field i am save that file in custom folder and for that i am using function named "aaiof_upload_dir" but in debug.log it's says function not found.my code is metion below.
`add_filter('upload_dir', 'aaiof_upload_dir'); //define function of aaior_upload_dir`
`$movefile = wp_handle_upload( $uploadedfile, $upload_overrides ); //using for upload file in  default uploads folder`  
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'aaiof_upload_dir');
`

```
if (!function_exists( 'aaiof_upload_dir')){
        function aaiof_upload_dir($upload) {
            $upload['subdir'] = '/contact_form';      
            $upload['path']   = $upload['basedir'] . $upload['subdir'];    
            $upload['url']    = $upload['baseurl'] . $upload['subdir'];      
            return $upload;
        }
     }
```